# How to update library version on multiple microservice pom.xml files

Tags: maven, spring-boot, pom.xml, microservices, auto-update

So lets say you have a common library repo. A release changes library latest version from 1.1 to 1.2.
Now any microservices that use this library need to have their pom.xml files updated manually.
Appreciate any suggestions on how to get around this.

Comment: I would suggest to implement a CI solution which will do the update via versions maven plugin and run the build (including tests) if successful just commit the changes...

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options;

- On the dependent projects pom.xml execute `mvn
  versions:use-latest-releases` command to automatically upgrade
  dependency versions.
- If all the projects are inheriting from same parent(and dependency configuration is done through dependency management), you can use `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=xx` on the aggregator pom.xml to upgrade versions.
- If versioning will happen quite often, Snapshot versions can be used.